# Есть ли CLI для NVidia Control Panel?

Tags: python, dll, nvidia

Перерыл весь интернет в поисках какой нибудь утилиты или более подробной информации по изменению настроек в панели управления в NVidia. Находил дллку, но там была проблема в том, что все функции подгружаются динамически, т.е. после запуска определенной функции. В написании кода на С, и тем более длл у меня не хватает знаний, да и каких либо "гайдов" на такое тяжело найти. Первоначальная цель менять яркость монитора через какой нибудь скрипт, приоритетно python. Есть ли готовые решения для такого?

PS. Стандартные методы смены яркости мне не подходят, только два варианта, физически кнопками на мониторах и через панель управления

Comment: [How do I change the screen brightness in windows using python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71113875/17799125); [How to Control Screen Brightness Through Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44232117/17799125)

Comment: @ΝNL993 Данные методы не подходит для меня, т.к. использует "внутренние" возможности Windows для изменения яркости. В моем же случае они просто выдают ошибку. Вариант с изменением яркости через powershell так же не подходит

Comment: А с Powershell-ом то, что не так?

Comment: @ΝNL993 Это вот команда которую я нашел для изменения яркости `(Get-WmiObject -Namespace root/WMI -Class WmiMonitorBrightnessMethods).WmiSetBrightness(1,50)` А вот лог который мне выдает эта команда https://pastebin.com/X9MtuyWW